# Primefaces upgrading exception: <f:validateRegex> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to update my application on primefaces-3.3.1 to primefaces-3.4.2. On updating dependencies (jar file) I am getting the following error.

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /test.xhtml @6,5 <f:validateRegex> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@6190d6d0
```

Xhtml code at this line :

```
 <p:inputText value="#{someBean.lastName}" required="true" id="lastName" validatorMessage="#{messages.lastNameMessage}">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="#{someOtherBean.lastNameRegexPattern}" />
 </p:inputText>
```

I guess Exception clearly says the now f:validateRegex cannot be nested into HtmlPanelGrid type component.

Following is the namespace declaration

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

So now how to fix it....?

Comment: No it says that it can't be nested inside `HtmlPanelGrid`. Is this your only `validateReqex` tag on whole page? Did you tries to remove it and see what's happening?

Comment: thanks for the correction partlov... not their are many validateReqex tag under HtmlPanelGrid.. rather if I talk about project their would be many instances where I have used the same instances.

Comment: Look like a strange bug. Have you reported it at their forum/issuetracker?

Comment: One more thing. Can you post xml namespace defined in root xml element of test.xhtml page? Especially definition for `xmlns:p`.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

Comment: @balusC just posted now Issue 5207

Comment: For the remainder, PrimeFaces components work fine? So if you remove the `<f:validateRegex>` and reload the page, then the `<p:inputText>` appears fine? This problem suggests that it isn't been interpreted/parsed and thus the closest `UIComponent` becomes the `<f:validateRegex>` parent instead.

Comment: I removed the <f:validateRegex> tag... than I am not getting this exception(as mentioned above) but I am getting null pointer exception in my another xhtml page.. which was earlier working fine with 3.3.1 version... Still I have to figure out y i am getting the null pointer exception.... In short with new version I am not able to load my application till now...